# JavaFX: Moving shapes get stuck inside each other when colliding

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a Pong-like game, and have implemented the code that moves the paddle (via user input) and the ball. I am currently working on the code for the collision between the ball and the paddle.

Everything seems to be working fine, except when I move the paddle directly onto the ball. This means that the ball collides with the bottom part or top part of the paddle, instead of the side of the paddle, which results in the ball getting stuck inside the paddle and stuttering rapidly.

I know that the motion is caused by the ball changing velocity every frame. I am still having trouble figuring out how to solve it.

I have tried implement a boolean variable to determine whether or not the ball already collided with the paddle during a frame. However, I am having some trouble going about implementing this logic into my code. In my main class, you will see some comments pointing out this boolean variable and what I intended to do with it.

Below are some of the major code snippets pertaining to my problem.

MainApp:

```
// ...
new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long currentTime) {
            ballInfo.setText("Ball (" + ball.getX() + ", " + ball.getY() + ")");
            leftPaddleInfo.setText("Left Paddle (" + leftPaddle.getX() + ", " + leftPaddle.getY() + ")");
            rightPaddleInfo.setText("Right Paddle (" + rightPaddle.getX() + ", " + rightPaddle.getY() + ")");

            // Give point and reset ball.
            if (ball.didCollideWithLeftWall(canvas)) {
                givePoint(rightPaddle);
                rightPaddleScore = rightPaddle.getPoints();
                rightPaddleScoreLabel.setText("Player 2 Score: " + rightPaddleScore);
                reset();
            }

            if (ball.didCollideWithRightWall(canvas)) {
                givePoint(leftPaddle);
                leftPaddleScore = leftPaddle.getPoints();
                leftPaddleScoreLabel.setText("Player 1 Score: " + leftPaddleScore);
                reset();
            }

            // Handle bouncing off of top and bottom walls
            ball.didCollideWithWalls(canvas);

            // Keep paddle in screen bounds
            if (leftPaddle.getY() <= canvasBounds.getMinY() + 5)
                leftPaddle.setY(canvasBounds.getMinY() + 5);
            if (leftPaddle.getY() >= canvasBounds.getMaxY() - 105)
                leftPaddle.setY(canvasBounds.getMaxY() - 105);

            if (rightPaddle.getY() <= canvasBounds.getMinY() + 5)
                rightPaddle.setY(canvasBounds.getMinY() + 5);
            if (rightPaddle.getY() >= canvasBounds.getMaxY() - 105)
                rightPaddle.setY(canvasBounds.getMaxY() - 105);

            if (leftPaddle.didCollideWith(ball)) {
                ball.setvX(-ball.getvX());
                ball.setX(ball.getX() + ball.getvX());
            }

            if (rightPaddle.didCollideWith(ball)) {
                ball.setvX(-ball.getvX());
                ball.setX(ball.getX() + ball.getvX());
            }

            // Update and render
            ball.update(ELAPSED_TIME_SPEED);
            leftPaddle.update(ELAPSED_TIME_SPEED);
            rightPaddle.update(ELAPSED_TIME_SPEED);

            gc.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

            gc.setFill(BALL_COLOR);
            ball.render(gc);

            gc.setFill(LEFT_PADDLE_COLOR);
            leftPaddle.render(gc);

            gc.setFill(RIGHT_PADDLE_COLOR);
            rightPaddle.render(gc);


        }

    }.start();
```

Paddle:

```
@Override
public boolean didCollideWith(Sprite other) {
    Ball ball = (Ball) other;
    double ballCenterX = ball.getCenterX();
    double ballRadius = ball.getRadius();
    double ballCenterY = ball.getCenterY();

    double halfWidth = this.getHalfWidth();
    double halfHeight = this.getHalfHeight();
    double centerX = this.getCenterX();
    double centerY = this.getCenterY();

    if (getName().toLowerCase().equals("left")) {
        boolean hitXBounds = ballCenterX - ballRadius <= centerX + halfWidth
                && ballCenterX - ballRadius >= centerX - halfWidth;
        boolean hitTopPartOfBall = ballCenterY - ballRadius <= centerY + halfHeight
                && ballCenterY - ballRadius >= centerY - halfHeight;
        boolean hitBotPartOfBall = ballCenterY + ballRadius <= centerY + halfHeight
                && ballCenterY + ballRadius >= centerY - halfHeight;

        return hitXBounds && (hitTopPartOfBall || hitBotPartOfBall);
    }

    if (getName().toLowerCase().equals("right")) {
        boolean hitXBounds = ballCenterX + ballRadius >= centerX - halfWidth
                && ballCenterX + ballRadius <= centerX + halfWidth;

        boolean hitTopPartOfBall = ballCenterY - ballRadius <= centerY + halfHeight
                && ballCenterY - ballRadius >= centerY - halfHeight;
        boolean hitBotPartOfBall = ballCenterY + ballRadius <= centerY + halfHeight
                && ballCenterY + ballRadius >= centerY - halfHeight;

        return hitXBounds && (hitTopPartOfBall || hitBotPartOfBall);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I have somewhat fixed the collision code in the Paddle class, so that now it is much more difficult to perform the mentioned bug. However, I am still getting the stuttering bug if the, for instance, the leftmost point of the ball comes right into contact with the rightmost point of the left paddle. If I were to time it just right, I can still get the ball stuck inside the paddle the same way as I could before (by moving it directly on top of/ bottom of it), but it will only create this bug IF the ball is still in front of the paddle.
I have changed the code above as well.